# Pandoc Jupyter (.ipynb) to Word (.docx) incorrect results

Tags: ms-word, jupyter, pandoc, nbconvert

Jupyter notebook (ipynb) to Word-format document (.docx) conversion just is not working correctly.  I have tried several approaches using jupyter nbconvert, pandoc, and commercial document format converters.  So far, none have produced appropriate results.  I have to believe there exists some way for pandoc to do the conversion correctly.  Thank you so much for your assistance on this.

The Word-format document should preserve these aspects of the Jupyter notebook:

- Headings numbered
- Code cells hidden
- Latex math expressions presented correctly
- Tables with images presented correctly
- Data.frame presented in same format as in Jupyter (pretty row-banded table)
- Kable data.frame presented in same format as in Jupyter (pretty row-banded table)

Here attached are a test Jupyter notebook and examples of some (inappropriate) results.

- PrintTest.ipynb is the Jupyter notebook to be transformed to Word-format.
- PrintTest.jpg  is a screenshot of the Jupyter notebook.
- PrintTest_1.html  from Jupyter, File > Download as > HTML Embedded (.html)

  - No heading numbers
  - Code cells exposed
- PrintTest_2.html  `jupyter nbconvert PrintTest.ipynb --to=html --template=toc2 --output PrintTest_2.html`

  - Sidebar table of contents exposed
- PrintTest_3.docx   pandoc PrintTest.ipynb -o PrintTest_3.docx

  - Latex math expression presented as plain text
  - Table with image not presented
  - Code cells exposed
  - Data.frame presented as plain text
  - Kable data.frame not presented
- PrintTest_4.docx   `pandoc PrintTest_2.html -o PrintTest_4.docx`

  - Latex math expression presented as plain text
  - Table with image not centered
  - Data.frame presented as plain text
  - Kable data.frame presented as plain text
- PrintTest_5.docx  `pandoc PrintTest.ipynb --mathjax -o PrintTest_5.docx`

  - Same as PrintTest_3.docx
- PrintTest_6.docx   `pandoc PrintTest_2.html --mathjax -o PrintTest_6.docx`

  - Same as PrintTest_4.docx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This post by a team targeting the issue of writing in Jupyter and exporting to Word](https://twitter.com/rowancockett/status/1483957860656508928) might interest you.

Answer (score 0):

With **Pandoc** there is a flag `-N` for some output writers (word, html, ...) to number the headings.

Example:

```
pandoc jupyter_file.ipynb -s -N -o new_word_file.docx
```

add `--toc`  if you also want to export a table of content:

```
pandoc jupyter_file.ipynb -s -N --toc -o new_word_file.docx
```